# this.dialogRef.close is not a function error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to unit test my dialogues. I'm expecting the dialogRef to be closed after action. However I'm getting the error:
 'Failed: this.dialogRef.close is not a function
  TypeError: this.dialogRef.close is not a function'

I've tried mocking but without any results.

I'm trying to unit test my dialogues. I'm expecting the dialogRef to be closed after action. However I'm getting the error:
 'Failed: this.dialogRef.close is not a function
  TypeError: this.dialogRef.close is not a function'

I've tried mocking but without any results.

Any suggestions?

```js
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from 
'@angular/core/testing';
import {CloneDialogComponent} from "./cloneDialog.component";
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, 
MatDialogTitle} 
from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform- 
browser/animations";

describe('CloneDialogComponent', () => {
    let component: CloneDialogComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CloneDialogComponent>;

    const dialogMock = {
    close: () => { }
    };

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          CloneDialogComponent
        ],
      imports: [
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
        providers: [
        {provide: MatDialogTitle, useValue: {}},
          {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {dialogMock}},
          {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: []}]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CloneDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('No calls onNoClick()', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onNoClick');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button = 
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#no');
    button.click();
    expect(component.onNoClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('Yes calls onYesClick()', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onYesClick');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const button = 
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#yes');
    button.click();
    expect(component.onYesClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('dialog should be closed after onYesClick()', async(() => {
    component.onYesClick();
    expect(component.dialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('dialog should be closed after onNoClick()', async(() => {
    component.onNoClick();
    expect(component.dialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

});
```

```js
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './cloneDialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cloneDialog.component.sass']
})

export class CloneDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CloneDialogComponent>,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close(false);
    }

    onYesClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need the brackets around `dialogMock`:

```js
{provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogMock},
```

And change your tests to use a spy to spy on the `close` function and then check if it has been called:

```js
it('dialog should be closed after onYesClick()', () => {
  let spy = spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'close').and.callThrough();
  component.onYesClick();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});

it('dialog should be closed after onNoClick()', () => {
  let spy = spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'close').and.callThrough();
  component.onNoClick();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();    
});
```

Working stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-jux8au?file=app%2Fclone-dialog%2Fclone-dialog.component.spec.ts).

Comment: Thanks so far! However the subscribe gives me the following: ERROR in src/app/dialogues/clone/cloneDialog.component.spec.ts(64,37): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<void>'. 

This also happens in your stackblitz code. 

I'm also not getting green coverage on the 'this.dialogRef.close(true);' part

Comment: Sorry I modified it in between, check it again [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-jux8au?file=app%2Fclone-dialog%2Fclone-dialog.component.spec.ts). Should work now, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working fine for me. You saved my hours.

Comment: Many thanks,   const dialogMock = {
    close: () => { }
   };